# Is "closed" an adverb or adjective in "pinch your nose closed"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech, parsing

> It is helpful to pinch your nose **closed** when you have to swallow something that tastes yucky, like cough syrup.

In this sentence, how should I understand the word "closed" is it adverb or adjective? I do not think "your nose (which is) closed..

Comment: "Closed" is clearly an adjective since it describes the state of one's nose after pinching it. Its function in the clause is that of **complement**.

Comment: I think you're confusing the past tense of the verb "to close", *closed* = shut, with the adverbs "*closely*" and "*close*" = referring to something under careful scrutiny or a short distance.

Answer (score 9):

The word **closed** is an adjective, describing the state of your nose after pinching. The structure is called **resultative**:

[Wikipedia "resulative"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative)
"In linguistics, a resultative (abbreviated RES) is a form that expresses that something or someone has undergone a change in state as the result of the completion of an event. Resultatives appear as predicates of sentences, and are generally composed of a verb (denoting the event), a post-verbal noun phrase (denoting the entity that has undergone a change) and a so-called **resultative phrase** (denoting the state achieved as the result of the action named by the verb) which may be represented by an **adjective**, a prepositional phrase, or a particle, among others. For example, in the English sentence *The man wiped the table clean*, the adjective *clean* denotes the state achieved by the *table* as a result of the event described as *the man wiped*."

(emphasis added)

In your example, the verb is "pinched", the noun phrase is "your nose", and the resultative phrase (an adjective) is "closed".

Comment: It's an optional **predicative** in that it relates to a predicand, "nose", and it can be omitted with no loss of grammaticality. Its function is that of resultative **complement**.